# Can I use a rust dragon as a mount?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, forgotten-realms, dragons, background

I'm relatively new to D&D, and after playing a bit with some friends, picked up a few books to learn more. In one book, *"[A PRACTICAL GUIDE TO DRAGON RIDING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0786949759)",* I was introduced to the idea of dragons as mounts. None of the usual dragons seemed to interest me, until I came across the Rust Dragon. I really liked the aesthetics of it, and the fact that it could rust metal.

But, I was wondering, could you have a rust dragon as a mount?

I searched this up, but only found mention of rust creatures, not rust dragons...

In addition, (I started to create a serious character for an upcoming campaign) can a character have a dragon to begin with, if say, they grew up with it or met it before the time the campaign is set? (Backstory, basically.)

Comment: 5e, If i'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Is your game set in the Dragonlance universe or Forgotten Realms? The book is Dragonlance but you tagged Forgotten Realms. It may or may not affect answers, but I believe it is good information to have

Comment: @Sdjz I believe the book is a spark for an idea, not as much a sourcebook.

Comment: ah, sorry, as I said I'm kind of new.

Comment: It looks like this: http://dnd.pfhoenix.com/downloads.php

Comment: @Spacelesswonder that link doesn't work

Comment: boof, here's another one: http://www.commonroomgames.com/DnD4_char_sheet-2_pgs.pdf This one ought to.

Comment: @Spacelesswonder That's a 4th edition sheet. So, if everyone is planning on using those, you're likely playing 4th edition.

Comment: Also, forgive our manners. Welcome to RPG.stackexchange. Feel free to take the [tour] if you'd like to get a better idea of the site. and you can find a lot of us in [chat] after you get up to 20 rep. Happy Gaming ^_^

Comment: Just for transparency, I voted to close so that we can really hammer out all of the details before someone answers. A close vote is not a super downvote and we're not mad :)

Comment: Yes, let's figure out really what edition and what setting.